# Plot KMeans Model

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means

I want to plot the centroids of KMeans ML but i dont get it. Add the picture of the graphic.

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
y = np.radians(df["LATITUD"]) #series
x =  np.radians(df[["LONGITUD"]]) #dataframe
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)
KMeans =cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5)
model2 = KMeans.fit(x_train, y_train)
model2 = KMeans.fit_predict(x_test)
centroids2 = np.array(KMeans.cluster_centers_)
labels = KMeans.labels_ 
K = 5
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, cmap="plasma", linewidths=1);
for k in range(K):
  plt.scatter(centroids2[k,0], centroids2[k, 1], s=100, marker='*', color='red')

plt.show()
```

Output:
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
3 plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, cmap="plasma", linewidths=1);
4 for k in range(K):
----> 5   plt.scatter(centroids2[k,0], centroids2[k, 1], s=100, marker='*', color='red')
6 plt.show()
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: can you please provide the shape of x_train ? and the shape of the centroids ? your error is coming from this `centroids2[k, 1]` , so I suspect that your centroids have the shape (K, 1).

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if centroids2 is a vector and not a matrix as you think, so you cannot access centroids2[k, 1] with k>0. To be more precise, it might be a (1,2) matrix, so index 0 works perfectly but index 1 is out of bounds because the second row doesn't exist.
Can you provide its shape and/or the code in which you used to create centroids2?